# Starting errors - "The root file system on /dev/sda1 requires a manual fsck"

Tags: boot, filesystem, fsck

When I start Ubuntu 16.10, the console shows the following errors:

```
/dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced
/dev/sda1: UNEXCEPTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUTUALLY
The root file system on /dev/sda1 requires a manual fsck
```

How can I solve this? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

To manually perform a file system check on your Ubuntu disk...

For 17.10 or older...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose <kbd>Advanced Options</kbd>
- choose <kbd>Recovery mode</kbd>
- choose <kbd>Root access</kbd>
- at the `#` prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

For 18.04 or newer... (or if the above steps don't work for you)...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Please remember to vote/accept my answer if it was helpful.